# How can I get a channel ID from YouTube?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I'm trying to retrive the data from my channel using the **YouTube Data API V3**.
For that I need my channel ID.
I've tried to find my channel ID from my YouTube account, and I failed in every single way.
If anyone have a single tip for me, I would be incredible glad.

**This is the URL that I'm using to retrieve the data:**

> https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?**id**=fjTOrCPnAblTngWAzpnlMA&**key**={YOUR_API_KEY}&part=snippet,contentDetails,statistics

The **ID** is for the channel ID, and the **key**, I'm replacing the {YOUR_API_KEY} with my API KEY generated at my Google API console.

**My channel ID is not:**
 - klauskkpm
 - klausmachado
 - klausmachado@gmail.com
 - fjTOrCPnAblTngWAzpnlMA

My channel is: http://www.youtube.com/user/klauskkpm

Comment: For those who come across this after the latest Data API revision (31st January, 2024), they provided the `forHandle` query parameter to get data of a handle/username. You can refer to this answer for details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78074066/2665606

Answer (score 258, accepted):

To obtain the channel id you can view the source code of the channel page and find either `data-channel-external-id="UCjXfkj5iapKHJrhYfAF9ZGg"` or `"externalId":"UCjXfkj5iapKHJrhYfAF9ZGg"`.

`UCjXfkj5iapKHJrhYfAF9ZGg` will be the channel ID you are looking for.

Comment: @Naveed Ahmad as this answer helps, view(in this case HTML) should not be used, since it's not reliable. They don't offer their HTML versionated or give an API access to it in anyway. To get any YouTube channel id, is wise to use the **mjlescano** answer, which uses the YouTube API.

Comment: @klauskpm true, since you were looking for your own id, but this answer gets you any channel ID and still does it 3 years later :)

Comment: @Yevgeniy, if you read my comment above, I told that it helps, but **mijlescano** answer can provide that using the official API, which is recommended.

Comment: Can you get a channel username using the channel ID?

Comment: You may have to search "externalId" now as I couldn't find anything for "channel-external-id"

Comment: After getting a bunch of YouTube channel ids manually, it looks like `data-channel-external-id` is for older channels (channels that were created *before* a certain date) and `externalId` is for newer channels (channels that were created *after* a certain date). I'm not sure when this "certain date" is, but if one doesn't work for you - try the other one

Comment: This worked well. I did not have YouTube Channel login details for the client & this saved my time. Thank you.

Comment: I just tried this on a channel that had the ID `UCW_OAaMdUH3fF00fh8_Koeg`. Their automatic "all uploads" playlist (which you can get to by clicking "play all" on the videos section of the channel) has the ID `UUW_OAaMdUH3fF00fh8_Koeg`. I don't know if it's always the same, but with U vs. C, but it might be.

Comment: This also works: View page source and search `<link rel="canonical"`. The `href` will contain the channel ID.

Comment: Doesn't work for not logged user

Comment: Also works searching on the html for "og:user" then you can get the full url with the respective channel id.

Comment: It's the string of characters after `l_id=`.

Comment: Adding another method I just found: `<meta itemprop="channelId" content="UC7ndkZ4vViKiM7kVEgdrlZQ">`

Answer (score 79):

An easy answer is, your YouTube Channel ID is **UC** + {YOUR_ACCOUNT_ID}.
To be sure of your YouTube Channel ID or your YouTube account ID, access the [advanced settings](https://www.youtube.com/account_advanced) at your [settings page](https://www.youtube.com/account)

And if you want to know the YouTube Channel ID for any channel, you could use the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18665812/1984885) @mjlescano gave.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?key={YOUR_API_KEY}&forUsername={USER_NAME}&part=id
```

If this could be of any help, some user marked it was solved in another topic [right here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13593769/retrieve-youtube-channel-info-for-vanity-channel).

Comment: I take it that it is not possible to get a channel ID without having an account ID. Is that correct?

Comment: The account ID and channel ID can be very similar, taking the UC part.
As I've said, you can enter the advanced settings page of your youtube account, or channel, and it will show you both IDs. Each channel/account creates both new channel and account ID.
So, they will ever exist.

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit unclear. I meant without actually having a google or youtube account.

Comment: Yes. If your trying to get your Channel ID ou Account ID, and you don't have an account or channel, both will not exist. Still, you can get this information for other channels. There is an example above.

Answer (score 32):

You can get the channel ID with the username (in your case "klauskkpm") using the filter "forUsername", like this:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?key={YOUR_API_KEY}&forUsername=klauskkpm&part=id
```

More info here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list

Comment: As heads up for others reading this, it does not always work. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62576403/how-to-get-a-youtube-channel-id-from-the-channels-username-which-includes-cyril) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37267324/how-to-get-youtube-channel-details-using-youtube-data-api-if-channel-has-custom)

Comment: what is the username for this channel for example https://www.youtube.com/@kali-ka6998 ? can i use the youtube API to lookup the channel ID from it?

Answer (score 30):

At any channel page with "user" url for example `http://www.youtube.com/user/klauskkpm`, without API call, from YouTube UI, click a video of the channel (in its "VIDEOS" tab) and click the channel name on the video. Then you can get to the page with its "channel" url for example `https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCfjTOrCPnAblTngWAzpnlMA`.

Edit:

Above is not working any more. But we can open Developer Tools (cmd + option + I) and try to find the URL there. Search by `channel_id` for some channels, it will show you, but NOT for all the channels.

By the way, if this is your own channel -- you can go here https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list and make request with part `snippet` and mine `true`.

Oh, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76285153/3622415). Thank you, just works!

Comment: This should get more attention. Such a simple solution.

Comment: it is not working anymore

Comment: Hmm thank you for letting us know. Then I guess we have to open Developer Tools (cmd + option + I) and try to find the URL there

Answer (score 20):

I just found the simplest way to find the channel ID of any YouTube channel !!

Step 1: Play a video of that channel.

Step 2: Click the channel name under that video.

Step 3: Look at the browser address bar.

Comment: It doesn't work anymore now.

Answer (score 20):

**Update: 2023**

1. Go to the [**About**](https://www.youtube.com/@StackOverflowOfficial/about) Tab of the YouTube channel
2. Under the `Stats` section click the `Share` button and select **Copy Channel ID**.

[image]

Answer (score 16):

*June 2021* edition.

1. Right click and view page source.
2. Search for `"externalId"`, the value follows.

Source: [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14366648/how-can-i-get-a-channel-id-from-youtube/68063136#comment79675683_16326307) by [Daniel](/users/43465/daniel) 2017.

Alternative: run this JavaScript in console:

```
ytInitialData.metadata.channelMetadataRenderer.externalId
```

Answer (score 11):

*As of 2022-06-23:*

Open Chrome Dev Tools (F12), and in the "Elements" tab, within the source code pane, depending on URL type:

**A. For channel URLs of type: [www.youtube.com/c/](http://www.youtube.com/c/)<channel_name>:**

Search for either:

- "externalId" - next to it there will be the **channel_ID**
- "channelUrl" - next to it there will be: https://www.youtube.com/channel/<**channel_ID**>

or run in the console:

```
ytInitialData.metadata.channelMetadataRenderer.externalId
```

(credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68063136/624597)

**B. For video URLs of type: [www.youtube.com/watch?v=](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=)<video_ID>:**

Search for either:

- "externalId" - next to it there will be the **channel_ID**
- "externalChannelId" - next to it there will be the **channel_ID**
- "ownerProfileUrl" - next to it there will be: https://www.youtube.com/channel/<**channel_ID**>

or run in the console:

```
ytInitialPlayerResponse.microformat.playerMicroformatRenderer.externalChannelId
```

Comment: There is no need to specify the date, it is logged as part of the answer.

Answer (score 10):

An **alternative** to get youtube channel ID by channel url without API:

```php
function get_youtube_channel_ID($url){
  $html = file_get_contents($url);
  preg_match("'<meta itemprop=\"channelId\" content=\"(.*?)\"'si", $html, $match);
  if($match && $match[1])
    return $match[1];
}
```

Comment: How do you run this?

Comment: I'm using PHP here

Comment: Remove ";" after if statement.

Answer (score 6):

Channel id with the current youtube version is obtained very easily if you login to YouYube website and select 'My channel'

[image: My channel]

Your channel ID will be displayed on the address bar of your browser
[image: channel id]

Answer (score 5):

Apparently there is a `channelId` attribute in video page's source code;

[image]

Comment: This answer needs more recognition

Answer (score 3):

https://www.youtube.com/account_advanced now provides both channel and user ids. See also https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/working_with_channel_ids .

Answer (score 3):

2017 Update: [Henry's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16326307/1171596) may be a little off the mark here. If you look for `data-channel-external-id` in the source code you may find more than one ID, and only the **first** occurrence is actually correct. Get the `channel_id` used in `<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS" href="https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=<VALUE_HERE">` instead.

Answer (score 2):

**2024 method using [yt-dlp](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp):**

You can get YouTube channel ID from channel username:

```bash
yt-dlp --print "%(channel_id)s" --playlist-end 1 https://www.youtube.com/@CNN/
```

```
UCupvZG-5ko_eiXAupbDfxWw
```

Answer (score 1):

To obtain the channel id you can do the following request which gives you the channel id and playlist id.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails%2C+statistics%2Csnippet&mine=true&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

**mine** parameter means the current authorized user

as u said channel id is prefixed with **UC+{your account id}** which you get while login, you can use this one also without requesting the above url you can directly call the channel api with your google id and just prefix with **UC**

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails%2C+statistics%2Csnippet&id=UC{your account id}&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have actually created the python function to help with obtaining the id of, it seems, any youtube channel. It uses requests (to get the raw html of the page) and beautifulsoup (to deal with this html and find this cagey id). Yes, it doesn't use any official API and therefore it`s less stable (because it relies on the structure of the youtube webpage), but, I think, this solution can still be helpful.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_yt_channel_id(modern_url: str):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(modern_url).content, "html.parser")
    try:
        return soup.find("meta", {"itemprop": "channelId"})["content"]
    except TypeError:
        return "Seems like the link is not valid."

while True:
    link = input("> ")
    print(get_yt_channel_id(modern_url=link))
```

To make this program work, you need to just insert the modern link (with @, e.: https://www.youtube.com/@KlausKazlauskas/videos), but it`s possible to modify this so that the function only takes the username:

```py
def get_yt_channel_id(username: str):
    modern_url = f"https://www.youtube.com/@{username}"
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(modern_url).content, "html.parser")
    try:
        return soup.find("meta", {"itemprop": "channelId"})["content"]
    except TypeError:
        return "Seems like the username is not valid."
```

Answer (score 1):

A most simple solution for **2023** is just to get ID from meta tags:

Just run this snippet in Channel page and it will alert the id for you to copy&paste:

```js
alert(document.querySelector('meta[property="og:url"]').getAttribute('content').split('/').at(4))
```

To keep things easy, I personally made a bookmarklet for myself using this code, so I could run it any time without opening the dev tools.

A code for bookmarklet:

`javascript:(function()%7Balert(document.querySelector('meta%5Bproperty%3D%22og%3Aurl%22%5D').getAttribute('content').split('%2F').at(4))%7D)()`

Answer (score 0):

To get Channel id

Ex: Apple channel ID

[image]

Select any of the video in that channel

[image]

Select iPhone - Share photos (video)

Now click on channel name **Apple** bottom of the video.

[image]

Now you will get channel id in browser url

[image]

Here this is Apple channel id: UCE_M8A5yxnLfW0KghEeajjw

Answer (score 0):

Try to search for regular expression `UC[-_0-9A-Za-z]{21}[AQgw]` in source code. This ID is presented even if channel has non-ASCII characters in URL:

[image]

Here is screenshot of internal viewer/editor of Midnight Commander, it has regexp search:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Alternatives to get the channel URL with its ID.

With a CSS selector by searching the channel homepage source code:

```css
body > link[rel="canonical"]
```

or with JS via the console:

```js
document.querySelector('body > link[rel="canonical"]').href
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method to find the ID of a channel that is not yours is to go to the channel page and press the red "Subscribe" button.

[image]

Then use the Chrome's Inspector tools Network tab and look for the POST request issued by the subscribe action. In the payload of this request you will find the channel id:

[image]

You can unsubscribe immediately after subscribing.

Answer (score 0):

I found a helpful solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75374713/3930234). First, you need to use the search endpoint with the username as a query parameter. Then you will be able to get the 'youtube#channel' section, along with the 'channelId'.

Answer (score -1):

Now in 2023, typing this in console should work:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('[itemprop="channelId"]')[0].content
```