# Youtube Api to fetch all videos on a Channel ( No longer available Error)

Tags: c#, youtube-api

We need video by channel-name list of YouTube (using API).
When I make a request I get the following error: *Error No longer available*

Youtube Api v3.

```
 Uri urlVideo = new Uri(String.Format("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/{0}/uploads/{1}", hipoConfig.canal_youtube, videoId));
                    //Uri urlVideo = new Uri(String.Format("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/users/{0}/uploads/{1}", hipoConfig.canal_youtube, videoId));

                //Google.YouTube.Video videoExistente = request.Retrieve<Video>(urlVideo);
                Video videoExistente = request.Retrieve<Video>(urlVideo);
```

Comment: I already loaded the video on Youtube, I need to check if this loaded, filtering their channel and ID

Comment: The above code if YouTube API v2, which was deprecated over a year ago. You need to use v3.

Answer (score 4):

I also had trouble getting video urls from a channel doing it your way so i switched to Google.Apis.YouTube.v3

[GitHub Page google Api dotnet client](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client)
or just download via nuget from visual studio

```
var yt = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer() { ApiKey = "YOURAPIKEY" });
var searchListRequest = yt.Search.List("snippet");
searchListRequest.Order = SearchResource.ListRequest.OrderEnum.Date;
searchListRequest.MaxResults = 12;
searchListRequest.ChannelId = "NEEDSYOURCHANNELID";
var searchListResult = searchListRequest.Execute();
```

You get an enumeration of SearchResults in searchListResult.Items

```
foreach (var video in searchListResult.Items.toList()) {
  var videoUrl = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + video.Id.VideoId
  // DO YOUR STUFF
}
```

To get your channel id look at this: [How can I get a channel ID from YouTube?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14366648/how-can-i-get-a-channel-id-from-youtube)