# youtube v3 api to get a channel id

Tags: api, youtube, youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api, youtube-channels

I am learning using youtube data api v3 to show list of playlists and further show list of videos of each play list from below link 
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3

I was able to get playlist for a channel id. And further each playlist, list of videos.

Before that I need channel id to do rest of operations. The input would be name of the channel and output should be details which includes unique channel id.
Below is the code snip that I was trying but I always get null result. Where as other part of code (by hard coding channel id) works great.

```
    public class GetChannelInfoAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ChannelListResponse> {
private static final String YOUTUBE_CHANNELLIST_PART = "snippet";
private static final String YOUTUBE_CHANNELLIST_FIELDS = "items(id,snippet(title))";

private YouTube mYouTubeDataApi;

public GetChannelInfoAsyncTask(YouTube api) {
    mYouTubeDataApi = api;
}

@Override
protected ChannelListResponse doInBackground(String... params) {
    final String channelName = params[0];

    ChannelListResponse channelListResponse = null;

    try {
        channelListResponse = mYouTubeDataApi.channels()
                .list(YOUTUBE_CHANNELLIST_PART)
                .setForUsername(channelName)
                .setAlt(ApiKey.YOUTUBE_API_KEY)
                .execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return channelListResponse;
}
```

}

Referring to
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list
and tried EXECUTE option with list (by YouTube username) gives 200(OK) success. but with above code its always null.

Comment: Forgot to mention forUser is any channel name [link](https://www.youtube.com/user/GoogleDevelopers). Example it is "GoogleDevelopers" is forUser.

Comment: Username is different than channel name. this question gives the best solution I found so far: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37267324/how-to-get-youtube-channel-details-using-youtube-data-api-if-channel-has-custom

Answer (score 3):

I came too late, but I have an answer. To get a Youtube channel's ID via v3 API make a HTTP GET request to https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search with these params:

- part=snippet
- type=channel
- fields=items%2Fsnippet%2FchannelId
- q={YOUTUBE_CHANNEL_NAME}
- key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Change value for `fields` key if you need more info.

Try it [here](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?hl=en_US#p/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list?part=snippet&q=GoogleDevelopers&type=channel&fields=items%252Fsnippet%252FchannelId)

---

Official Guide: [Work with Channel IDs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/working_with_channel_ids)

Answer (score 1):

Youtube data v3 API: Here is the get request to find channel_id by channel name

[https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?forUsername={CHANNEL_NAME}&part=snippet,id&key={API_KEY}](https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?forUsername=%7BCHANNEL_NAME%7D&part=snippet,id&key=%7BAPI_KEY%7D)