# How to get youtube channel id using channel custom name?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

My question is very similar to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37267324/how-to-get-youtube-channel-details-using-youtube-data-api-if-channel-has-custom),
I want to get channel id using channel custom name.

The answer on the question mentioned above which is:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id%2Csnippet&q=annacavalli&type=channel&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

doesn't work on small channels, for ex. when I run it with this channel: https://www.youtube.com/AnnaShearerfashionfettish it returns nothing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Youtube channel details using Youtube data API if channel has custom url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37267324/how-to-get-youtube-channel-details-using-youtube-data-api-if-channel-has-custom)

Comment: as you can see, I've already mentioned in the question that it is very similar to this question, but the answer there doesn't work with me. So I asked this question.

Comment: then you should ask for clarification on the existing question not open a second question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates

Comment: I asked for clarification at the answer there, but how can I like reshow this question to be able to get an answer for my case?

Comment: For those who come across this after the latest Data API revision (31st January, 2024), they provided the `forHandle` query parameter to get data of a handle/username. You can refer to this answer for details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78074066/2665606

Answer (score 3):

It's very easy, using `curl` and `grep`.

**Command**

```sh
channel_name='DOVASYNDROMEYouTubeOfficial' #change this as you like
curl --silent "https://www.youtube.com/c/${channel_name}/videos" |\
    grep -o -P '(?<=canonical" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/)[^"]*'
```

**Output**

```
UCq15_9MvmxT1r2-LLjtkokg
```

Answer (score 2):

I didn't find a direct way to do this. I did a GET request to get the channel page HTML and parse it.

I used Jsoup to parse the html response.

```
val doc = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(body)
val links = doc.select("link[rel=canonical]")
val channelUrl = links.first().attributes().get("href")
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippetforUsername={username}&key={your key}`

Remember to change `{your key}` to your API key, and `{username}` to the desired username.

Comment: I don't need to get channel id for user. I need it for custom channels.