# Get ChannelID from Youtube Custom URL

Tags: javascript, youtube-data-api

Is there any way that I can get the channel ID of a Youtube Channel by having its custom url (using the Youtube API) ?

Example:

A custom url is like:

> https://www.youtube.com/onepiece

I want to get its channelID, so that I have the link like:

> www.youtube.com/user/OnePieceUK

Comment: please provide full examples of the URLs

Comment: See answers and comments in this possible duplicate of [**How can I get a channel ID from YouTube?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14366648/how-can-i-get-a-channel-id-from-youtube)

Comment: I'm already using that request when i have the channelID or username. It's different from this case, since this is a custom URL

Comment: I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/37947865/revisions) outlines the only solution I've seen.

Comment: For those who come across this after the latest Data API revision (31st January, 2024), they provided the `forHandle` query parameter to get data of a handle/username. You can refer to this answer for details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78074066/2665606

Answer (score 3):

I recently had a similar requirement where I knew the custom URL of a youtube channel and I want to get the channel id. So I went to the YouTube channel and clicked on a random video to get the Video ID from the web browser url. Once I get the Video Id, then I used the "Videos: list" API to get the video details:

```
https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=[VEDIO_ID]&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]
```

The retuned data contained all the metadata information about the video, including ChannelId :-).

It may not be the most smartest and elegant way of doing things, but it solved my purpose.

Answer (score 3):

Elaborating on [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63081162/8327971), I'll note here the following facts:

1. In YouTube URLs of form `https://www.youtube.com/c/NAME` or `https://www.youtube.com/NAME`, `NAME` is a channel's [`custom URL`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#snippet.customUrl). (See [this official account](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2657968) from Google support.)
2. In YouTube URLs of form `https://www.youtube.com/user/NAME`, `NAME` is a channel's *user name*. User names are a *legacy* feature of the API v3; not every channel has one attached; no channel is required to have one attached. (See [this official statement](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35173130#comment5) from Google staff from 2013-07-11.)

The two API concepts -- *custom URLs* and *user names* -- encompass two different categories.

The public (MIT licensed) Python 3 script [`youtube-search.py`](https://gist.github.com/stvar/f57e9792c3dc49fab2690247d6ee74de) referred by my answer quoted above is able to search the API for custom URLs and respectively query the API for user names:

```
$ python3 youtube-search.py --custom-url onepiece
UC6LPb3zSebrzU_0Yclpwb4Q

$ python3 youtube-search.py --user-name OnePieceUK
UC6LPb3zSebrzU_0Yclpwb4Q
```

Note that `youtube-search.py` requires a valid API key to be passed to it as argument of the command line option `--app-key` or, otherwise, passed on as the environment variable `YOUTUBE_DATA_APP_KEY`. (Use the command line option `--help` for brief helping info.)

Comment: your first example doesn't work: _"error: custom URL "onepiece": no associated channel found"_. But `python3 youtube-search.py --custom-url @onepiece` works. Note the `@`. I'm not sure if this is an error in the provided usage example, or an error in the python script itself, so I'm just reporting this issue to you in a comment.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

resp = requests.get('https://www.youtube.com/onepiece')
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'html.parser')

channel_id = soup.select_one('meta[property="og:url"]')['content'].strip('/').split('/')[-1]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

try my bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Enter the YouTube channel name
echo "Enter the YouTube channel name or url:"
read channel_name

# Check if the channel name contains "youtube.com" and add it if necessary
if [[ ! "$channel_name" == *youtube.com* ]]; then
    channel_name="https://www.youtube.com/$channel_name"
fi

# Use YouTube get the channel ID
channel_id=$(curl -s -A "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0" --compressed $channel_name | grep -oP '(?<=externalId":")[^"]*(?=",)')

# Print the channel ID and original channel name
echo "The channel ID for ${channel_name##*/} is: $channel_id"
```