# Can you get a YouTube Channel ID from a username from the API?

Tags: javascript, youtube-data-api

I am currently using the [YouTube Data Channel API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list), which allows me to retrieve the Channel ID of any given username.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?key={KEY HERE}&forUsername={USERNAME}&part=id,snippet&order=date
```

It works for the majority of usernames, but for some reason it chooses not to work for others.

For example, if you visit the URL: `https://youtube.com/impaulsive`, we can see that the username must be `impaulsive`.

However, if you search that through the Channel API via the `forUsername` attribute, it returns no results - even though it is their actual username and directs you to their official channel.

Is there a way to retrieve the Channel ID from a username?

Comment: Please update your question or else add comments under my answer below if needing further help (and/or clarifications).

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is very much recurrent with YouTube Data API (here, on SO was recently tackled several times: just issue the following SO search query: [`[youtube-data-api] forUsername`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5Byoutube-data-api%5D+forUsername)).

Basically, you have to acknowledge two things:

1. User names are a *legacy* feature of the API v3; not every channel has one attached; no channel is required to have one attached. (See [this official statement](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35173130#comment5) from Google staff from 2013-07-11.)
2. If you come across URLs of form `https://www.youtube.com/c/NAME` (or even `https://www.youtube.com/NAME`), then `NAME` is not necessarily (though it could be) the YouTube user name of an YouTube channel. `NAME` is a channel's [`custom URL`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#snippet.customUrl), a different category. (See [this official account](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2657968) from Google support.)

Your example -- `impaulsive` -- fits well with point 2 above, because it *is the custom URL* of the channel of which ID is `UCGeBogGDZ9W3dsGx-mWQGJA`, yet *is not the user name* of any channel:

```bash
$ python3 youtube-search.py --custom-url impaulsive
UCGeBogGDZ9W3dsGx-mWQGJA

$ python3 youtube-search.py --user-name impaulsive
youtube-search.py: error: user name "impaulsive": no associated channel found
```

The script [`youtube-search.py`](https://gist.github.com/stvar/f57e9792c3dc49fab2690247d6ee74de) used above is a public (MIT licensed) Python 3 program (that I developed) implementing an [algorithm that searches for custom URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63081162/8327971) and also is querying the API for user names.

Note that `youtube-search.py` requires a valid API key to be passed to it as argument of the command line option `--app-key` or, otherwise, passed on as the environment variable `YOUTUBE_DATA_APP_KEY`. (Use the command line option `--help` for brief helping info.)

Answer (score 0):

No need to use any type of api, you can directly get the channel id using axios.

I have found this way from doing inspect of a youtube channel.

here is the code to get channel id using channel username:

to install axios on node.js

**npm install axios**

```
const axios = require('axios');

let Url = "https://www.youtube.com/@triggeredinsaan"
let channelUrl = Url.replace("/user", ""); //this will replace /user to the supported format

//supported format: https://www.youtube.com/@username

          var url = new URL(channelUrl)
 const { data } = await axios.get(url.href)


          
let Id = data.split(`<link rel="canonical" href="`)[1];

       let Result = Id.split(`">`)[0];

return console.log(ResultId); //Your channel id returns in provided format: https://www.youtube.com/channel/Id
```

Comment: While your solution would work, please note that if you make too many automated requests like this in a short time, YouTube will block your IP address for 2-3 days. You won't be blocked if you use the Data API.

Comment: how can I get data api?

and this is only one time process when a discord user set their youtube channel stats for their server so its very less chances to make many requests, it may make 3 max requests in an hour I guess?