# How to find channel information from channel name?

Tags: youtube-data-api

I am facing problem of fetching channel information by using channel name.

For example, https://www.youtube.com/c/mkbhd/videos is the url. here **mkbhd** is channel name. Is the any API endpoint which gives information by using channel name?

I tried with channel list(by YoutTube username) but received different channel information

Channel 1 - https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCBJycsmduvYEL83R_U4JriQ

Channel 2 - https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCmf_VrB73I-eJ3fq0adaOkg

I tried getting information of channel 1 with its channel name (above url - mkbhd), but got information of channel 2

Attaching screentshots
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this issue has been tackled time and again on this forum. I myself have a recent series of answers pertaining precisely to this issue; see the items obtained from SO's search box  on the search terms `user:8327971 custom URL` or `user:8327971 forusername`.

Comment: Follow this answer to gain knowledge about these things: [Can you get a YouTube Channel ID from a username from the API?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65709170/8327971) *Custom URLs* are very often taken as *user names*: an URL of form `https://www.youtube.com/c/NAME` that points to a channel indicate that the respective channel has its custom URL being `NAME`.

Comment: Your `mkbhd` is the custom URL of the channel `UCBJycsmduvYEL83R_U4JriQ`, while, at the same time, is the user name of the channel `UCmf_VrB73I-eJ3fq0adaOkg`. (These as shown by the Python script mentioned within the answer I quoted above.)

Comment: so can you suggest me how to tackle this situation because i want to store correct data if users on my platform enters such urls.

and Thank you so much sir for instant response

Comment: Python Script makes things easier but isn’t there any support from YouTube because the my tech stack does is not python based.

Comment: @stvar [this url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37267324/how-to-get-youtube-channel-details-using-youtube-data-api-if-channel-has-custom) also having same problem which i am facing.

Comment: (Quote from you): *so can you suggest me how to tackle this situation because i want to store correct data if users on my platform enters such urls*: I suggest to proceed as indicated by the *summary* at the end of [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65369038/8327971).

Comment: i believe it will increase my API time 