# How to convert YouTube channel URL's to channel ID's?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm building an application in which users provide a URL to a YouTube channel, and with this input I need to convert the URL to a YouTube channel ID (ex: `UCUZHFZ9jIKrLroW8LcyJEQQ`). The YouTube Data API documentation appears to lack instructions on converting Custom URL's and Shortened URL's to channel ID's.

**There are 4 variants of URL's for YouTube Channels:**

1. https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCUZHFZ9jIKrLroW8LcyJEQQ (ID-based URL)
2. https://www.youtube.com/user/partnersupport (Legacy username URL)
3. https://www.youtube.com/c/YouTubeCreators  (Custom URL)
4. https://www.youtube.com/YouTubeCreators (Shortened URL, either a Custom URL or Legacy username URL)

**ID-based URL**

"This is the standard URL that YouTube channels use. It uses your unique channel ID, which is the numbers and letters at the end of the URL."

```
Channel ID is in the URL
https://www.youtube.com/channel/<channel_id>
```

**Legacy username URL**

Usernames can be converted to channel ID's using YouTube Data API v3

```
https://www.youtube.com/user/<user>

Channel ID returned with API response from:
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=id&forUsername=<user>"&key=<API key>
```

**Custom URL**

I'm unable to find any official documentation on converting this URL variant to a channel ID. Currently, I'm using the YouTube Data API to search for the `<custom URL>` value. This method is not 100% reliable.

```
https://www.youtube.com/c/<custom URL>

This API query performs a search, can return multiple channels, and the correct channel 
may not be in the results.
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id%2Csnippet&q=<custom URL>&type=channel&key=<API key>
```

**Shortened URL**

This URL variant can refer to either a Custom URL or a Legacy username URL. I currently have no method of reliably converting this variant.

```
https://www.youtube.com/<custom URL | User>
```

**Questions:**

1. What is the most reliable method of converting a **custom URL** to a channel ID?
2. What is the most reliable method of converting a **shortened URL** to a channel ID?

*Note:* I am NOT interested in scraping the URL to find the channel ID, as this is a violation of YouTube's terms of service. At scale, this could result in IP addresses being blacklisted from interacting with YouTube/Google services.

REF: https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6180214?hl=en

Comment: Please follow the [series of answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A8327971+custom+url) I gave recently to this very issue. (I cannot repeat those answers here -- that would be against SO guidelines.) The most (almost 100%) reliable way to obtain channel IDs from custom URLs is described by [Obtaining a channel id from a youtube.com/c/xxxx link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63081162/8327971). Shortened URLs are [custom URLs](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2657968).

Comment: Thank you for your response, I had not thought about using the `channels.list` API endpoint to compare the `customUrl` value.

In contrast to what you mentioned, according to https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6180214?hl=en shortened URL's can refer to either a custom URL or a Legacy username URL.

Comment: Indeed you're right: in case of an URL of form `https://youtube.com/NAME`, `NAME` could be an *user name*, if it's not a *custom URL*. That is that, one has to consider `NAME` as an custom URL by look it up, using the *almost reliable* algorithm I quoted above; in case (1) it's a custom URL then OK; otherwise, (2) in case the algorithm fails, then `NAME` could still be a custom URL or an user name.

Comment: The alternative (2) continues by checking whether `NAME` is a user name using the 100% reliable `Channels.list` query for `forUsername`. In the case the endpoint indicates that `NAME` is an user name then OK; else `NAME` is not an user name, but could still be a valid custom URL that the algorithm at (1) was not able to identify.

Comment: I have to correct my latest comment above (*The alternative (2) continues by...*) as follows: In the case `Channels.list` indicates `NAME` not to be an user name, then FAIL; otherwise, check whether the [`customUrl`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#snippet.customUrl) property of the channel returned by `Channels.list` is equal to `NAME` or not. In case of equality, then OK; otherwise FAIL: `NAME` could still be a custom URL of a channel that we cannot know by current API means (but which is known to the YouTube's back-end).