# Response has no items array in it

Tags: youtube-data-api

When making a GET request to the API for GoogleDevelopers channel, I'm getting the following result as expected.

Request: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&forUsername=GoogleDevelopers&key=MY_API_KEY

Response:

```json
{
    "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
    "etag": "w0k6RzPUxkrdtxJxL2f_V-wMmtE",
    "pageInfo": {
        "totalResults": 1,
        "resultsPerPage": 5
    },
    "items": [
        {
            "kind": "youtube#channel",
            "etag": "P81a-u1XylztNDFIIotdR2fpRn8",
            "id": "UC_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw",
            "contentDetails": {
                "relatedPlaylists": {
                    "likes": "",
                    "favorites": "",
                    "uploads": "UU_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

When making the request to my own Youtube Channel, Im just getting the following response.

Request: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&forUsername=JOSCHLI1304&key=MY_API_KEY

```json
{
    "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
    "etag": "nR8QCUcJvaTfaxr2vzyDGZfMitE",
    "pageInfo": {
        "totalResults": 0,
        "resultsPerPage": 5
    }
}
```

The items Array is missing...

I have no idea why this API Call works for all other channels, but not for my Channel?

I hope somebody can help me out.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

That happens because `JOSCHLI1304` is not the user name of any YouTube channel:

```bash
$ python3 youtube-search.py --user-name JOSCHLI1304
youtube-search.py: error: user name "JOSCHLI1304": no associated channel found

$ python3 youtube-search.py --custom-url JOSCHLI1304
youtube-search.py: error: custom URL "JOSCHLI1304": no associated channel found

$ python3 youtube-search.py --search-term JOSCHLI1304 --type channel
UCtwQthkBopRVzS5NrneQ8ZQ: JOSCHLI1304

$ python3 youtube-search.py --channel-url UCtwQthkBopRVzS5NrneQ8ZQ
joschli1304svideosundtutorials
```

The third command above (the one containing the command line argument `--search-term`) shows that there's a channel -- `UCtwQthkBopRVzS5NrneQ8ZQ` -- that has *its title* set to `JOSCHLI1304`.

Furthermore, the fourth command above shows that the channel of which ID is `UCtwQthkBopRVzS5NrneQ8ZQ` has it's [`custom URL`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#snippet.customUrl) set to something that's close to the name you're looking for: `joschli1304svideosundtutorials`.

**Appendix**

The script [`youtube-search.py`](https://gist.github.com/stvar/f57e9792c3dc49fab2690247d6ee74de) used above is a public (MIT licensed) Python 3 program (that I developed) implementing an [algorithm that searches for custom URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63081162/8327971) and also is querying the API for user names.

Note that `youtube-search.py` requires a valid API key to be passed to it as argument of the command line option `--app-key` or, otherwise, passed on as the environment variable `YOUTUBE_DATA_APP_KEY`. (Use the command line option `--help` for brief helping info.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But can you tell me, what my Username is? What do I have to input in the URL?

Comment: @joschli1304: User names are a *legacy* feature of the API v3: not every channel has one attached and no channel is required to have one attached. (See [this official statement](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35173130#comment5) from Google staff from 2013-07-11.) Your channel -- `UCtwQthkBopRVzS5NrneQ8ZQ` -- does not have a user name as per the API response (no `items` array).

Comment: @joschli1304: For what concerns your second question -- *What do I have to input in the URL?* --, please be more specific: to what URL are you referring? If you refer to the argument of the parameter [`forUsername`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#forUsername), then, again, you may issue that API endpoint with (really) *any* value of that argument: the API will never return an response referring to your channel  (since this channel *has no user name attached*).

Comment: Thank. Is it possible to set a user name to a YouTube channel?

Comment: Unfortunately, @joschli1304, currently there's no way one could attach a user name to his/her channel. I'd warmly recommend you to handle your channel within your app (any channel for that matter) based on IDs: these are real unique identifiers; they are here for quite a long time and will stay as such for the long run.