# Find YouTube user name for a channel

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to use the YouTube Data API to fetch channel data for particular channels.  According to the documentation, I can use list (by channel ID) or list (by YouTube username)

```
Search by channel ID
https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet&id={ChannelID}&key={APIKey}

// Get channel by YouTube username
https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet&forUsername={Username}&key={APIKey}
```

The channel ID can be retrieved by going to YouTube in a browser and search for the channel by name and then when you select the channel; the channel ID is part of the URL like this:

`https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCbTw29mcP12YlTt1EpUaVJw`.

This particular channel is for Sean Allen and his YouTube URL is:

`https://www.youtube.com/SeanAllen`.

I would have thought that the YouTube username would be `SeanAllen`, but it is not because, when I use that term in the API request, I get 0 results.

However, in my own case, my channel ID  is `UCOWdR4sFkmolWkU2fg669Gg` and the search by channel ID works to fetch my channel data.  My YouTube URL is:

`https://wwww.youtube.com/StewartLynch`

and, if I use `StewartLynch` as the username, I can use that 2nd API request to fetch the same data.

So, my question is, how does one find the correct YouTube username for a channel?  Apparently it is not what is used in the channel URL.

Comment: For those who come across this after the latest Data API revision (31st January, 2024), they provided the `forHandle` query parameter to get data of a handle/username. You can refer to this answer for details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78074066/2665606

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're raising is recurrent time and again on Stack Overflow. I myself already tackled all faces of it (just issue either of the following SO search terms: `user:8327971 custom URL` or `user:8327971 forUsername`).

The short story is as follows: *don't rely much on YouTube user names*.

User names are a *legacy* feature of the API v3: not every channel has one attached and no channel is required to have one attached. (See [this official statement](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35173130#comment5) from Google staff from 2013-07-11.)

Here is what YouTube Data API returns for the two names -- `SeanAllen` and `StewartLynch` -- of your post:

```bash
$ python3 youtube-search.py --custom-url SeanAllen
UCbTw29mcP12YlTt1EpUaVJw

$ python3 youtube-search.py --user-name SeanAllen
UCRGhxM6u14Uv309cC0ywEqA

$ python3 youtube-search.py --custom-url StewartLynch
UCOWdR4sFkmolWkU2fg669Gg

$ python3 youtube-search.py --user-name StewartLynch
UCOWdR4sFkmolWkU2fg669Gg
```

As you can see, `StewartLynch` is both the custom URL and the user name of the channel of which ID is `UCOWdR4sFkmolWkU2fg669Gg`.

But, in case of `SeanAllen`, things are not that simple since there's a channel -- `UCbTw29mcP12YlTt1EpUaVJw` -- that has its custom URL set to this name; and, at the same time, there's a different channel -- `UCRGhxM6u14Uv309cC0ywEqA` -- that has its attached user name set to the this very same name.

This situation is very much perennial with YouTube: many channels out there have in common this property.

The final note, which closes your question:

> how does one find the correct YouTube UserName for a channel?

The [`Channels.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) API endpoint queried with the request parameter [`forUsername`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#forUsername) *does return* the correct user name of a given channel (if the respective channel has attached an user name).

The ambiguity stems from the fact that URLs of form:

`https://www.youtube.com/NAME`

may well represent either a channel of which user name is `NAME` or a channel of which custom URL is `NAME`. The two cases [can be set apart](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6180214?hl=en) only by the (not-completely reliable) [procedure of searching for custom URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63081162/8327971) (which is implemented already by the script `youtube-search.py`).

---

Above I make use of my public (MIT licensed) Python 3 script [`youtube-search.py`](https://gist.github.com/stvar/f57e9792c3dc49fab2690247d6ee74de); this script is able to search the API for custom URLs and respectively query the API for user names.

Note that `youtube-search.py` requires a valid API key to be passed to it as argument of the command line option `--app-key` or, otherwise, passed on as the environment variable `YOUTUBE_DATA_APP_KEY`. (Use the command line option `--help` for brief helping info.)

Comment: @Stewart Lynch: If you need further help and/or clarifications, feel free to just post comments below this answer.

Comment: Thank you for such a thorough explanation.  I really appreciate the time you took to explain the conundrum.

Comment: @Stewart Lynch: Note also that you may well handle this instance of the (proverbial) Gordian Knot by simply scraping out the channel ID from the HTML text of a page under an URL of form `https://www.youtube.com/NAME`; but, if you were to observe the specifications of the [DTOS](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/developer-policies), then you could not employ this simpler procedure, since scraping is forbidden activity (section III.E.6 of that document).