# Get channel ID from channel name with Youtube Data API

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am looking for a way how I can receive the YouTube channel ID from a channel name by the Google YouTube API, for example from `ChrisDowningFitness` in:

`https://www.youtube.com/c/ChrisDowningFitness`.

So far, I tried:

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?key=MY_KEY&forUsername=ChrisDowningFitness&part=id`;

however, this is only working for a user name, not the channel name.

Having a look at the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list), I wasn't able to identify any parameter allowing me to search for a channel name.

Does anyone have an idea, how I can get this working?

Comment: This is the answer to your question: [Obtaining a channel id from a youtube.com/c/xxxx link?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63081162/8327971)

Comment: For those who come across this after the latest Data API revision (31st January, 2024), they provided the `forHandle` query parameter to get data of a handle/username. You can refer to this answer for details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78074066/2665606