# How to find the forUsername parameter for a specific channel

Tags: python, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm new to working with the YouTube API v3, and StacOverflow in general, so sorry for any mistakes.

Right now I am having trouble understanding the `forUsername` parameter. For some channels, such as *YouTube* or *H2ODelerious*, I am able to find the correct channel. When it comes to using channels such as *leagueoflegends* or *playoverwatch* (both of these being the names of the channels when it comes to composing a URL of form `https://www.youtube.com/c/...`) I do not find the correct channel and neither find no channel at all, nor one with no views or subscribers.

Here is my code:

```
channelStats = testConnection.channels().list(
    part ='statistics',
    forUsername ='Youtube'
)
response = channelStats.execute()
```

If anyone knows whether there is another way to properly identify the correct channel while using the `Channels.list` method, please let me know. (Am using YouTube Data API v3 through Google's Client Library for Python and Python 3.8.)

Answer (score 5):

I did answered thoroughly to precisely your kind of inquiry quite recently. I'd warmly recommend you to absorb these two posts:

1. [How to get a YouTube channel ID from the channel's username which includes Cyrillic characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62576403/how-to-get-a-youtube-channel-id-from-the-channels-username-which-includes-cyril/62578656#62578656) and
2. [Obtaining a channel id from a youtube.com/c/xxxx link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63046669/obtaining-a-channel-id-from-a-youtube-com-c-xxxx-link/63081162#63081162)

Here, I'll only emphasize that the `forUsername` request parameter has the following official specification:

> [**forUsername**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#forUsername) (string)
>
> The `forUsername` parameter specifies a YouTube username, thereby requesting the channel associated with that username.

But, the name `NAME` under an URL of form:

`https://www.youtube.com/c/NAME`

*is not necessarily the YouTube username* of the respective YouTube channel. *`NAME` is that channel's [custom URL](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2657968)*, a different category.

According to [an official Google staff post](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35173130#comment5) from 2013-07-11, *it's not a requisite that every channel have attached an username*. Google's issue tracker records even a [`forCustomUrl` feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/165676622)  that has been rejected for the time being (at least for the API's road map of 2020).

The second post I quoted above provides an algorithm that'll produce the channel ID associated to a given custom URL. Moreover, that post also provides a Python function that implements the algorithm.

A public (MIT licensed) Python 3 script -- [`youtube-search.py`](https://gist.github.com/stvar/f57e9792c3dc49fab2690247d6ee74de) -- is linked to that post too; the script implements both the custom URL algorithm and the `forUsername` API querying.

This script produces the following outputs when invoked with each of the searched names your post above contains:

```
$ python3 youtube-search.py --user-name YouTube
UCBR8-60-B28hp2BmDPdntcQ

$ python3 youtube-search.py --custom-url YouTube
youtube-search.py: error: custom URL "YouTube": no associated channel found

$ python3 youtube-search.py --user-name H2ODelerious
youtube-search.py: error: user name "H2ODelerious": no associated channel found

$ python3 youtube-search.py --custom-url H2ODelerious
youtube-search.py: error: custom URL "H2ODelerious": no associated channel found

$ python3 youtube-search.py --search-term H2ODelerious --type=channel
UCClNRixXlagwAd--5MwJKCw: H2ODelirious
UCagP0Z1PVAAOpYV4HKy6w9w: H2o Delerious
UC6x4XQ6cqBzxGlSlCwcyUBw: H2O Delerious
UCzOeqwelmnbBDf3bIHde0EQ: H2O Delerious
UCLmpVRE4XIEem_1EwHxqtXQ: H2O Delerious plays
UCxxWGzT90DG1gk2pnvcRt2w: h2o delerious fan artist
UCYH7TzSISrC-2Mfy3TyjUDQ: H2O DELERIOUS Flores
UCfRjtX1qzFbCptULo529HsA: Jbz2swag
UCYd0SDTRQ54K1UQ-OkQd_7w: Jehowen
UCjozfwXXP7bEGPDFpAtgsYQ: LittleCool Me

$ python3 youtube-search.py --user-name leagueoflegends
UCvewcgPDiYrVNiyh8kpOnFQ

$ python3 youtube-search.py --custom-url leagueoflegends
UC2t5bjwHdUX4vM2g8TRDq5g

$ python3 youtube-search.py --user-name playoverwatch
UCM9KGdihR14QHFeyOsA-kgA

$ python3 youtube-search.py --custom-url playoverwatch
UClOf1XXinvZsy4wKPAkro2A
```

Note that `youtube-search.py` requires a valid API key to be passed to it as argument of the command line option `--app-key` or, otherwise, passed on as the environment variable `YOUTUBE_DATA_APP_KEY`. (Use the command line option `--help` for brief helping info.)

Also note that among the channels resulted from invoking the search script through:

`$ python3 youtube-search.py --search-term H2ODelerious --type channel`,

only two have the [`customUrl`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#snippet.customUrl) property set, as follows:

```
$ python3 youtube-search.py --channel-url UCClNRixXlagwAd--5MwJKCw
h2odelirious

$ python3 youtube-search.py --channel-url UCYd0SDTRQ54K1UQ-OkQd_7w
jehowen
```

Comment: for others who read this answer: you have to install google api lib for python: `pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client`