# Inconsistent and invalid response from YouTube Data API's PlaylistItems.list

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have sent the following request to get the playlist ID of the IGN channel:

`https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list?apix=true&apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22contentDetails%22%5D%2C%22forUsername%22%3A%22ign%22%7D#try-it`.

Then I extracted `contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads`, which is the main playlist ID of this channel.

Afterwards I used this playlist id in the following request to get corresponding videos:

`https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22contentDetails%22%2C%22snippet%22%2C%22id%22%2C%22status%22%5D%2C%22maxResults%22%3A50%2C%22playlistId%22%3A%22UU5YfR2K_rXeIy7bseOKky6Q%22%2C%22prettyPrint%22%3Atrue%7D#try-it`.

The problems are:

1. Inconsistent response (sometimes `404`, sometimes `200`) on same request;
2. When I get `200`, no videos were returned.

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: I confirm the same behavior described by the OP. When the API responds with HTTP status code `400`, the JSON error response looks like the following: `{"error":{"code":404,"message":"The playlist identified with the request's <code>playlistId</code> parameter cannot be found.","errors":[{"message":"The playlist identified with the request's <code>playlistId</code> parameter cannot be found.","domain":"youtube.playlistItem","reason":"playlistNotFound","location":"playlistId","locationType":"parameter"}]}}`.

Comment: When the HTTP status code is `200`, the JSON response has an empty `items` array: `{"kind":"youtube#playlistItemListResponse","etag":"...","items":[],"pageInfo":{"totalResults":0,"resultsPerPage":50}}`.

Comment: Also note that the YouTube's Web UI shows the [Ign](https://www.youtube.com/user/Ign) channel to have no content (no uploaded videos).

Comment: I'd recommend to report this issue to Google directly through its [own issue tracker site](http://issuetracker.google.com/).

Comment: @stvar , it looks like it is my mistake, I though that i am looking for this channel https://www.youtube.com/c/IGN.
In any case it should return consistent response.

Comment: Even if by mistake, in my opinion, you revealed an API bug.

Comment: [My public script](https://gist.github.com/stvar/f57e9792c3dc49fab2690247d6ee74de), for your *custom URL* `IGN`, produces `UCKy1dAqELo0zrOtPkf0eTMw`.

Comment: See [one of my answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64302234/8327971) w.r.t. to the difference between `forUsername` and *custom URLs*.

Comment: worked fine, when I used UUKy1dAqELo0zrOtPkf0eTMw, thanks

Comment: I have the same issue. The 404 portion of it is reported here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/174471495 I am in the process of finding a way to make it reproducible for the Google folks. And I am preparing to report the 200 but empty list part.

Comment: Yeah, this is a bug on there side and it only started recently

Comment: @analog-nico please, consider post your comment as an answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior of the `playlistItems` API endpoint has changed recently.

It started to return a `404` for upload playlists of many channels that have no uploaded videos. I [reported this to Google](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/175930697) and they decided to add this change to their API documentation without changing the API itself.

**This means we now have to assume that if we get a `404` for an upload playlist then the associated channel has no uploaded videos.**

However, I also found a case in which the `playlistItems` API endpoint returns a `404` for a channel that does indeed have uploaded videos. I just [reported this issue as well](https://issuetracker.google.com/176416911) and am waiting for their response.

@OP: The upload playlist id that you provided is one that returns a `404` for a channel that has no uploaded videos. So that exactly matches what I just described. However, this may not fully cover your listed problems but I can tell that you use the right API requests.

The additional problems that you listed – which seem to originate from upload playlists that you did not report here – may be worth reporting as an issue to Google. Just follow the links above to find out where you can submit an issue. One piece of advice: You must provide the necessary information that allows the Google employees to reproduce your issue with 100% certainty. Otherwise they will mark your issue as "Won't Fix (not reproducible)".