# YouTube API subscriber count incorrect because of channels with the same name

Tags: python, google-api, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Code:

```
import requests
import json

key = 'key' #api key
url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&key='+ key +'&forUsername='

youtuber = input('What\'s the name of the youtuber: ') #get youtuber name
url += youtuber.lower() #youtuber name all lowercase

r = requests.get(url) #get data from youtuber channel webpage

try:
    subs = json.loads(r.text)['items'][0]['statistics']['subscriberCount']
except:
    print('Your youtuber doesn\'t exist ):')
    exit()
print(youtuber,"has",subs,"subscribers! Woohoo!")
```

This is okay:

Input: Google

Output: Google has 9640000 subscribers! Woohoo!

This is **not**:

Input: Markiplier

Output: Markiplier has 84900 subscribers! Woohoo! (Actually, his main channel has 27.8M subscribers)

I run into the unfortunate issue of channels with the same name. How do I prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to acknowledge the following peculiarity of YouTube site: it permits (by design) that the very same name -- in your case `Markiplier` -- to be a channel's custom URL and, at the same time, to be the (legacy) user name of another channel.

Please read the [first few paragraphs of my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64302234/8327971) to a very much related question. From there, you'll get a pretty good idea about the difference between the two (sometimes confusing) concepts: *channel user name* and *channel custom URL*.

Concretely, if you'll make use of my Python3 public script [`youtube-search.py`](https://gist.github.com/stvar/f57e9792c3dc49fab2690247d6ee74de), you'll see that there are two different channels that exhibit the behavior I just described w.r.t. the name `Markiplier`:

```
$ python3 youtube-search.py --user-name Markiplier
UCxubOASK0482qC5psq89MsQ

$ python3 youtube-search.py --custom-url Markiplier
UC7_YxT-KID8kRbqZo7MyscQ
```

Note that `youtube-search.py` requires a valid API key to be passed to it as argument of the command line option `--app-key` or, otherwise, passed on as the environment variable `YOUTUBE_DATA_APP_KEY`. (Use the command line option `--help` for brief helping info.)

A further [`Channels.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) API endpoint query on the following URL:

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?id=UCxubOASK0482qC5psq89MsQ,UC7_YxT-KID8kRbqZo7MyscQ&part=id,snippet,statistics&fields=items(id,snippet(title,description,customUrl),statistics(subscriberCount))&maxResults=2&key=...`

will confirm the difference you've experienced:

```json
{
  "items": [
    {
      "id": "UCxubOASK0482qC5psq89MsQ",
      "snippet": {
        "title": "markiplier",
        "description": "I will no longer be updating this channel! All my new videos with be uploaded to markiplierGAME! Please re-subscribe on that channel to stay up-to-date on my videos!"
      },
      "statistics": {
        "subscriberCount": "85000"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "UC7_YxT-KID8kRbqZo7MyscQ",
      "snippet": {
        "title": "Markiplier",
        "description": "Welcome to Markiplier! Here you'll find some hilarious gaming videos, original comedy sketches, animated parodies, and other bits of entertainment! If this sounds like your kind of channel then please Subscribe Today!\n\nTotal Charity Raised ▶ $3,000,000+",
        "customUrl": "markiplier"
      },
      "statistics": {
        "subscriberCount": "27800000"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Now, to make a summary of my points w.r.t. your question -- *I run into the unfortunate issue of channels with the same name. How do I prevent this?* --, I note the following:

1. Be sure what is that you look to obtain from the API: *custom URLs* and *user names* are different API concepts.
2. If you're trying to obtain info about a channel for which you have its *user name*, then use `Channel.list` endpoint queried with an appropriate `forUsername` parameter.
3. If you're trying to obtain info about a channel of given *custom URL*, then use the procedure and Python code I described in my answer to this question [Obtaining a channel id from a youtube.com/c/xxxx link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63081162/8327971). Also be prepared for possible failure of that procedure (due to way the API is currently implemented, it may well happen that the procedure fails on certain valid custom URLs).