# YouTube API | How do you reliably find channel's username or channelId?

Tags: request, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

For my application I need to retrieve a channel's ID, which can be done using a channel's username via `channels().list(..., forUsername=username, ...)`.

The issue I have is that a channel's username is not as obvious as you would think. For example, *talkSPORT*'s channel's username is actually *talkSPORTMagazine*. The only way I have been able to extract this is from their main page's URL.

> - [talkSPORTMagazine](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22id%22%5D%2C%22forUsername%22%3A%22talkSPORTMagazine%22%7D)
> - [talkSPORT](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22id%22%5D%2C%22forUsername%22%3A%22talkSPORT%22%7D)

However, a channel's main page's URL does not reliably include their username: sometimes it does, sometimes it includes their ID, or sometimes nothing at all.

If I don't use a channel's *actual* username then I cannot extract their `channelID`, something I need to request videos.

Is there a way I can *reliably* find a channel's username?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is unfortunately negative: there's no reliable way to find a channel's user name.

That's because user names are a *legacy* feature of the API v3: not every channel has one attached and no channel is required to have one attached. (See [this official statement](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35173130#comment5) from Google staff from 2013-07-11.)

I warmly recommend to make your app such that it not rely on user names identifying channels; do arrange your app logic (both internal and external) such that to base it on *channel IDs*.

For what concerns channel URLs using user names, please follow this answer of mine: [How to find the forUsername parameter for a specific channel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64302234/8327971).