# YouTube API Returns Wrong Channel's Videos

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to retrieve videos from "nbaonespn" channel, and instead this API is giving me videos from other channels.

I tried this API call to Youtube API and was expecting to receive videos from "nbaonespn" channel.

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=*******&part=id&forUsername=nbaonespn&maxResults=3&order=date`

However, I received videos from Fox news and a random channel name Willjum.

Here is the response:

```json
{
    "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
    "etag": "lIkxZx_k0uHgRMuqgEf9hPAnnPA",
    "nextPageToken": "CAMQAA",
    "regionCode": "US",
    "pageInfo": {
        "totalResults": 1000000,
        "resultsPerPage": 3
    },
    "items": [
        {
            "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
            "etag": "98v9BVyMoXcCr_-3UmFgOCHwFGE",
            "id": {
                "kind": "youtube#video",
                "videoId": "Vi6XFEoSrtY"
            }
        },
        {
            "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
            "etag": "KCo7llEWVz4_pWSSyPTdwCLERWw",
            "id": {
                "kind": "youtube#video",
                "videoId": "LcjB3uGPtvg"
            }
        },
        {
            "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
            "etag": "-nLmHAse_B2BmMKSHncQJqcYZV0",
            "id": {
                "kind": "youtube#video",
                "videoId": "4c1eqt8FVDE"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64302234/18877953

Comment: You can also read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75843807) to understand YouTube channel ids.