# YouTube API: How to get the channel id by channel name?

Tags: youtube-api

Is it somehow possible to get the channel ID by a channel name ([www.youtube.com/somechannelname](http://www.youtube.com/somechannelname))? In my case I only have the channel name, but have to retrieve data from the channel (but for this I need the ID).

Comment: https://commentpicker.com/youtube-channel-id.php

Answer (score -1):

See: [How can I get a channel ID from YouTube?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14366648/how-can-i-get-a-channel-id-from-youtube)

> To obtain the channel id you can view the source code of the channel
> page and find either
> `data-channel-external-id="UCjXfkj5iapKHJrhYfAF9ZGg"` or
> `"externalId":"UCjXfkj5iapKHJrhYfAF9ZGg"`.
>
> `UCjXfkj5iapKHJrhYfAF9ZGg` will be the channel ID you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, but how does it work via the YouTube API (i.e. PHP)?