# How to get YouTube channel ID from video or channel page using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, firefox

`window?.ytInitialPlayerResponse?.videoDetails?.channelId` worked recently, but now `ytInitialPlayerResponse` is undefined. So how can I get the YouTube channel ID from a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2LSyizrk8-0) or [channel](https://www.youtube.com/@xkcd_whatif) page using JavaScript? This is for a [Firefox bookmarklet](https://paperless.blog/youtube-channel-web-feed-bookmarklet).

**Update:** For some reason my original bookmarklet now works on the video and channel pages above. Maybe it's a thing about new channels, where their ID is not exposed? I'll keep the question open in case anyone has a suggestion for something which seems like it could be more robust than `window?.ytInitialPlayerResponse?.videoDetails?.channelId`.

This is not a dupe of [How can I get a channel ID from YouTube?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14366648/96588). This question is specific to JavaScript, and to the two types of pages mentioned above, and none of the JavaScript-based answers work anymore.

Answer (score -2):

Try it without the question marks...

```
window.ytInitialPlayerResponse.videoDetails.channelId
```

Comment: No the question marks are just a shorthand for returning `undefined` early if a property is undefined, rather than trying to look up a sub-property. That said, I can't fault you for posting this, since both my original code and your code works now.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).