# Where to find the youtube API Key?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I followed all the steps. I selected my desired API (YouTube Data API) and created a project.
I am searching now for about 20 minutes but I can't find the API Key?
My user interface is in german, is it possible that it is named to something else than API Key? Maybe Clientschlüssel (Client Key) ?

This is all I found:

[image]

There is also a JSON object, but no API Key:

```
var myInfos = {
    "web":{
        "client_id":"censored",
        "project_id":"censored",
        "auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
        "token_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
        "auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"censored",
        "client_secret":"censored",
        "redirect_uris":["https://localhost/ex/YouTube/index.html"],
        "javascript_origins":["http://localhost"]
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? It appears that you've created an **OAuth 2.0 client ID**, which is used for authenticating the users of your application. Depending on your needs, perhaps you need a ** Dienstkontoschlüssel** (Service account key)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to walk through this again to make sure you have done it properly.

1. Make sure you have a Google account.
2. Log into the developer console at: https://console.developers.google.com/
3. Create a project
4. THEN, select YouTube data API
5. Click create credentials on the right hand side of the screen.
6. Choose where you will call the API from
7. Pick public or User.
8. Obtain your API Key.

Optional: restrict your key.

I just walked though all of this and have been given a key myself.

Comment: I already have a project and it seems like I can't create another one... I can't find a button where it says 'create new project'

Comment: In this scenario, you just need to click on the dropdown for your current project (I'm assuming it is the white block) and then on the right hand side of the screen that pops up is a plus sign for create new project. I don't believe making a new project will help you get a new API key, as the option is present on my credential slide.

Comment: Ahh I did not see it because I am using a browser plugin which makes everything dark and it is literally invisible.. thx!

Comment: Great! I'm glad you found it. Best of luck!

Comment: Links to the developer consoles (where all your projects are) can only be found at the bottom of the https://developers.google.com/ page. It would be SUPER helpful if they put these in the navbar. 

(I was looking for my youtube API keys that I created 2 years ago, and it took me a while to figure out how to get back to the "projects" area)

Answer (score 3):

1. sign into https://developers.google.com
2. https://console.developers.google.com/project - Create Project - enter Project Name - Create
3. select newly created project
4. Go to APIs Overview
5. click + Enable APIS AND SERVICES
6. type "YouTube" - select Youtube API v3 - click Enable
7. click Credentials - "Create Credentials" - API key
8. Copy and paste API key to text editor, e.g. notepad (save)

Answer (score 1):

I finally found it!
You have to go to `Zugangsdaten` (Credentials) and then click on `Anmeldedaten erstellen` (create credentials), now you can select API Key!

[image]